# Redshift - Max window function with Condition

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, window-functions

I'm trying to get the max value of a specific field in the last 3 months, last 6 months and max since inception with respect to a specific date and partitioned by part_id.

For max since inception, I used, below query.

```
select 
 part_id,
 date_field,
 MAX(val) OVER(partition by part_id order by date_field rows unbounded preceding) as max_since_inception
FROM my_table;
```

How do I add a condition to get the max value only in the last 3 months of my date_field?

```
Eg. if date_field is 2020-09-25, 
max_l3m must have max value between 2020-06-25 and 2020-09-25;
max_l6m must have max value between 2020-03-25 and 2020-09-25;
max_since_inception must have max_value since inception till 2020-09-25
and partitioned by part_id
```

[image: table sample here]

Comment: provide some sample data and your desired output

Comment: @Fahmi I've put the desired output with sample data

Answer (score 1):

Redshift doesn't support window frames, so you are stuck with a self join or some other complicated construct:

```
select t.part_id, t.date_field,
       max(case when tprev.date_field > t.date_field - interval '3 month' then value end) as max_l3m,
       max(case when tprev.date_field > t.date_field - interval '6 month' then value end) as max_l6m
from t join
     t tprev
     on tprev.part_id = t.part_id and tprev.date_field <= t.date_field;
```

You might also want to limit the lookback period to 6 months, if that is the longest timeframe you really need.

Comment: This seems to crash redshift with the size of the data I have. I am running with a single node.